# Relocating legend from GeoPandas plot

Tags: matplotlib, geopandas

I'm plotting a map with legends using the GeoPandas plotting function. When I plot, my legends appear in the upper right corner of the figure. Here is how it looks like:
[image]

I wanted to move the legends to the lower part of the graph. I would normally would have done something like this for a normal matplotlib plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(4.5,10))
lima_bank_num.plot(ax=ax, column='quant_cuts', cmap='Blues', alpha=1, legend=True)
ax.legend(loc='lower left')
```

However, this modification is not taken into account.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can access the legend defined on the `ax` instance with `ax.get_legend()`. You can then update the location of the legend using the method `set_bbox_to_anchor`. This doesn't provide the same ease of use as the `loc` keyword when creating a legend from scratch, but does give control over placement. So, for your example, something like:

```
leg = ax.get_legend()
leg.set_bbox_to_anchor((0., 0., 0.2, 0.2))
```

A bit of [documentation of set_bbox_to_anchor](http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend.set_bbox_to_anchor), though I don't find it extraordinarily helpful.

Answer (score 31):

This could be done using the `legend_kwds` argument:

```
df.plot(column='values', legend=True, legend_kwds={'loc': 'lower right'});
```

Comment: `'loc': 'lower right'` produced for me `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loc'`  
while  
`'location': 'bottom'` worked fine

Answer (score 0):

If you have a horizontal legend and you're trying to simply reduce the gap between the legend and plot, I recommend the `colorbar` approach detailed at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/330175/32531 along with passing the `pad` `legend_kwd` argument:

```py
legend_kwds={"orientation": "horizontal", "pad": 0.01}
```