# geopandas legend_kwds seems to be ignored

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a geodataframe which I'm plotting from, code looks like this

```
ax = df.plot(column='cap',
             cmap='Oranges', figsize=(16, 9),
             linewidth=0.5,
             edgecolor='black',
             facecolor='red',
             legend=True,
             legend_kwds={'frameon': True, 'loc': 'center left',
                          'title': 'My legend Title', 'fontsize': 24}
             )
```

I am trying to increase the size of the legend markers and played around with the legend_kwds, however it's always fixed at the right side of the plot, it doesn't matter what I pass in the dict.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: What is the version of `geopandas`?

Comment: `legend_kwds` including `loc` are honoured for me, geopandas v0.4.0 (matplotlib 2.2).  If it is just the legend location that is a problem, perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39844366 for a workaround.